# Squash n commits into one, when n includes a merge

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to clean up a development branch.  There was a branch created off of this branch with multiple commits, including a merge of the development branch back into the feature branch.  The feature branch was then merged into development.

So in development I have some commits:

```
"Some commit"
"More commit"
"merge branch development into feature1"
"Another commit - start of feature work"
"First commit that does not include feature1"
```

I would like to smash the first 4 commits into one commit.  But no matter what I try things get screwed up because of the merge.  Due to the merge work that was performed on the development branch gets smashed into the feature1 commit.

Is smashing those commits possible?

**EDIT**, tried using rebase as follows:

When I try 'git rebase -i HEAD~4' I get the following:

```
pick 3e217ba Another commit - start of feature work
pick b44463a merge branch development into feature1
pick 625ba76 More commit
pick 996b98e Some commit
```

And I can change that to

```
pick 3e217ba Another commit - start of feature work
squash b44463a merge branch development into feature1
squash 625ba76 More commit
squash 996b98e Some commit
```

However the problem with that is I am squashing commit 'squash b44463a merge branch development into feature1' which I do not want to do.  Because that merge contained work from the development branch that was merged into the feature1 branch.  I want to make this commit look like it was just feature1 stuff.

If I remove the merge line when rebasing, it fails.

Comment: have you tryied git squash?

Comment: @codeWizard I have.  I think the problem I am running into w/ squash is that squashing in the merge is squashing in commits that were not part of the feature.  This is because that merge pulled the development branch changes into the feature1 branch.

Comment: Try to follow the answer and see if its working foryou,

Comment: Are you trying to remove the merge commit altogether?

Comment: @merlin2011, not sure if I want to remove the merge commit or not.  Needed to merge development into the feature1 branch to pull in some changes.  But now feature1 branch is merged into development.

Comment: @lostintranslation, I'm not sure I understood you correctly, so please let me know if my answer is not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to factor out the development merge from the feature1 work, for this you want to squash together the three commits that are feature work, and then separate out the merge.

Try the following order at the interactive rebase editor.

```
pick 3e217ba Another commit - start of feature work
squash 625ba76 More commit
squash 996b98e Some commit 
pick b44463a merge branch development into feature1
```

Comment: Awesome!  Didn't think about reorder, that was the key.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `s` for squash = it will combine all the commits into a single commit.

[image]

---

You also have the --root flag in case you need it

try: `git rebase -i --root`

**--root**

```
Rebase all commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting them with
an <upstream>.

This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a branch.  
When used with --onto, it will skip changes already contained in `<newbase>`   
(instead of `<upstream>`) whereas without --onto it will operate on every 
change. When used together with both --onto and --preserve-merges, all root 
commits will be rewritten to have `<newbase>` as parent instead.`
```

Comment: See edit.  This is what I have already tried.  Does not squash only feature1 changes, due to fact that there was a merge of development into feature1.